Seeing an error while running a supabase flutter gis query
I have a query I'm using that was working. I added a postgis integration and want to start querying by nearest 100km. I replaced the column list with '*' to simplify it. I have latitude and longitude stored in my table as columns.
var query = supabase
      .from('table1')
      .select('''
  *,
  table2 (*),
  round((st_distance("location", st_point(longitude, latitude)::geography) * 0.000621371)::numeric, 1) as dist_miles''')
    .lt('ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), ST_MakePoint(${initialLocation.longitude}, ${initialLocation.latitude})::geography)', 100000)
    .gt('created_at', DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 60)))
    .lte('price', priceRange.start == 1000 && priceRange.end == 1000 ? priceRange.start : 1000000000)
    .gte('price', priceRange.start == 100000 && priceRange.end == 100000 ? priceRange.start : 0);

final response = await query
      .order('created_at', ascending: false)
      .limit(5)
      .range(offset, offset + 5);

This query was working before I added the postgis extension and I tried to run query based on distance, the first .lt('ST_Distance... is what I want to start measuring.
But I run into this error, not sure why
PostgrestException(message: "failed to parse select parameter (*,round((st_distance("location",st_point(longitude,latitude)::geography)*0.000621371)::numeric,1)asdist_miles)" (line 1, column 250), 
code: PGRST100, 
details: unexpected "(" expecting "...", field name (* or [a..z0..9_$]), "*", "count()" or ")", hint: null)



This PostgrestException seems to indicate something else is in the mix namely PostgRest, is that the case?  If so explain how that is being used. 2) Not sure how the query worked before you added PostGIS when you are using PostGIS functions in it? Add answers as text update to question text.


Updated the question, it's all based around supabase, so a lot of it is abstracted away

You did not actually answer the questions in my comment. You are going to need to de-abstract the process in order to solve the issue. Said issue seems to be with table2 (*), in the select(), if I am following the error message correctly.
